# Cannot View Progress Bar (Horizontal) while using application. (Navigation Drawer)

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have used Navigation Drawer (template) from Android Studio. As per the tutorial, I can easily see the progress bar in 'content_main' xml. However, whenever, the activity starts the progress bar is no where to be seen. I have tried many tutorials including using FrameLayout in place of ConstraintLayout, using Progress Bar inside of Toolbar using Linear Layout. Please help me out. the code for 'content_main' is given below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="parts.tractor.versa.com.versatractorparts.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/bg_progress_bar_webview"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"/>
```

and Java file is as below:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    final Activity activity = this;
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
            // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Your Url In this Method with Default ProgressBar.

```
private void startWebView(String url) {

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContestActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(ContestActivity.this, "Error:" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I was looking for the Progress Bar that I have used and want to know the exact reason as to why it's not showing.